# IOS swift convert dictionary to json string creates invalid JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode, dictionary

I have a json object which I receive from iOS api javascript callback and I will send the same json to php back end to validate it. In android everything works fine, but in IOS app the problem is when I receive the `message.body` which is json, it shows as below.

```
{
    OrderNumber = 01869756;
    "customer_key" = SLApO64gAktgmuLl;
    "order_address" = "{\"address\":\"No. 7 Ogwui Road Enugu\",\"city\":\"Enugu\"}";
    "order_amount" = 242550;
    "order_currency" = "&#8358;";
    "order_currency_iso" = NGN;
    "order_shipping" = 0;
    "order_stores" =     {
        zOEZPU8sGCADHRbr8yw4 = {
            amount = 242550;
            currency = "&#8358;";
            delivery = 0;
            total = 242550;
        };
    };
    "order_subtotal" = 242550;
    "order_subtotal_cent" = 24255000;
    "order_tax" = "4123.35";
    "order_tax_cent" = 412335;
    "order_total" = "246673.35";
    "order_total_cent" = 24667335;
    status = 200;
}
```

When I pass the above IOS format to php backend `json_decode($payload)` it always return null. Please how do I convert this to real json format I have tried below code but it doesn't work?

```
 let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode("\(message.body)") {
      if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
         print("dictFromJSON", jsonString)
      }
  }
```

And also I tried this

```
if let response = message.body as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
   let encoder = JSONEncoder()
      if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode("\(response)") {
          if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
             print("dictFromJSON", jsonString)
          }
      }
}
```

But the above code output something like below which is not a valid json.

```
[
        "OrderNumber": 01869756,
        "customer_key": SLApO64gAktgmuLl,
        "order_address": {\"address\":\"No. 7 Ogwui Road Enugu\",\"city\": \"Enugu\"};
        "order_amount": 242550,
        "order_currency": &#8358,
        "order_currency_iso: NGN,
        "order_shipping" = 0;
        "order_stores":    {
            zOEZPU8sGCADHRbr8yw4 = {
                amount = 242550;
                currency = "&#8358;";
                delivery = 0;
                total = 242550;
            };
        };
        "order_subtotal": 242550,
        "order_subtotal_cent: 24255000,
        "order_tax": 4123.35,
        "order_tax_cent": 412335,
        "order_total": 246673.35",
        "order_total_cent": 24667335,
        "status" = 200
    ]
```

Comment: What data type is `message.body`?

Comment: @Sweeper its a json

Comment: @VahagnGevorgyan the json is correct, it working fine on Android

Comment: @Peter It can't be "json". "json" is not the name of a type in Swift. Is it `[String: Any]` or `String` or `Data` or something else?

Comment: You can see the type of `message.body` by doing `print(type(of: message.body))`. Please do that, and tell me what type it is.

Comment: @Sweeper the type is `__NSFrozenDictionaryM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the type of `message.body` is `__NSFrozenDictionaryM`, you can turn it into a JSON string using `JSONSerialization`:

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message.body, options: []) {
    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
       print("dictFromJSON", jsonString)
    }
}
```

If you want to see the JSON formatted prettily, pass `.prettyPrinted` to `options:`.

---

The `JSONDecoder` API does not work so well here as you are dealing with JSON in the form of a dictionary. `JSONDecoder` works best when you have `Codable` types.